# User List view in Napili template

Tags: community, list-view, napili

I have a requirement to Show all the user who are able to access the Community built on the Napili Temaplate.
There is a pre-existing page for the same named User List, i assume.
But the URL is need to be in format : 
**/profile/:objectName/:filterId**

I tried using giving parameter like : /profile/:User/:00Bb0000001iwGY

where 00Bb0000001iwGY is the id of an list view on User.
But still I am unable to save it and getting error: Please replace each parameter with the appropriate value.

Comment: Try removing the : /profile/User/00Bb0000001iwGY

Comment: this should be a comment,  unless you further elaborate on why your solution should work.