# Chatter User List in Napili Community

Tags: community, user-record, napili

I'm looking to see if I can add a user list in my Napili Community that lists Name and allows the user to follow them. Basically I'm looking for something like that "Chatter" > people sub-tab that appears in classic. I was surprised that it doesn't appear to be an out of box component.

I tried using community page > user list and also looked at this post ([User List view in Napili template](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129778/user-list-view-in-napili-template)) but I didn't have much luck with getting that working.

Any help and or advice is much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Napili template (Customer Support in Winter 17) does not support Users yet although document does not highlight but it is not supported yet

So alternative would be to build your own lightning component for this .